# Can you include only top 10 records in SOQL group?

Tags: soql, aggregate, group-by

I have the following Query

```
[Select Supplier__c, Avg(Total_Sales__c) from Submittal group by Supplier__c order by Purchase_Date__c DESC]
```

The issue is that I only want to include the latest 10 records in my average total sales calculation. Is such a thing possible? It must be done with SOQL, not Apex as querying all the submittals will be way over the limit for query rows returned.

Comment: You'd likely need a custom rollup (implemented via `Apex Trigger`) to make this requirement work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last 10 avgs for each supplier then you are going to have to use something like [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You can partition by supplier with purchase_date descending where row num < 10. That should give you a start on getting what you need.

Comment: would this not only give me the 10 suppliers with the most recent purchase dates? I want all suppliers, just the last 10 Total_Sales__c averaged from each

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Does SOQL support the ROW_NUMBER() function? A google search isn't coming up with any documentation, could you post an example of how you'd use it in SOQL?